# Arch Installation - Pacstrap kills internet connection

Tags: linux, installation, internet, ethernet, arch-linux

I successfully installed Arch on my 7-year-old "side" laptop last weekend with no difficulty, and want to install Arch on my 3-year-old "main" laptop.  Before  running `pacstrap /mnt base base-devel` I `ping www.google.com` to confirm I have internet.  Immediately attempting  to run the pacstrap command, my internet gives out and I can't download any files.  Internet returns once I physically disconnect and reconnect the ethernet wire (or returns on its own after ~30 minutes).  I even tried using the same ethernet wire I used to install Arch on my side laptop.

My network controller:

```
Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3979
Kernel driver in use: alx
Kernel modules: alx
```

Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `ip a` immediately after you run `pacstrap`?

Comment: `2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP gorup default qlen 1000`.  I did a `diff` on the before and after having internet and running pacstrap, and  the only line that changed a few lines below from there:`valid_lft 3599sec preferred_lft 3599sec` to `valid_lft 3568sec preferred_lft 3568sec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a hardware-specific bug.  The following command solved the problem:

```
ifconfig <interface name> mtu 9000
```

Where `<interface name>` for me was enp2s0.

Credit:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70761

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1560975#p1560975